# Deploy asp.net core webapi app from VS Code to IIS web server errors

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am new to asp.net core, Im used to Visual Studio 2017 and how publishing web apps works with that.

I rewrote a simple login endpoint in asp.net core using VS Code that was previously written in Visual Studio 2017 using MVC and tried to publish it following articles I googled. I'm getting an error when I browse the app in IIS. Something else looks weird too, when I view the published files they look incomplete. I'm new to VS Code creating webapi core apps so maybe I am wrong. I'll attach a screen shot of the published files.

The error I am getting is: "
HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway
There was a connection error while trying to route the request.
"

I have installed the .NET Core SDK and required installs on the IIS machine and set up the APP Pool for No Managed Code as well.

### Web Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\LB_CONNECT_API_2.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

### SCREENSHOT Of PUBLISHED FILES

[image: Published webapi files from VSCODE]

I tried editing web.config and removing the V2 from AspNetCore

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
   [ApiController]
   public class LoginController : ControllerBase
     {
      // POST: api/Login
       public User Post(User user)
      {

          SqlDataReader reader = null;
          SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection
          {

               ConnectionString = @"Server=ServerName;Database=DB;User ID=User;Password=password;"
           };

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                CommandText = "lb_Login",
                Connection = myConnection
            };
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", user.Email);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", user.Password);
            myConnection.Open();
            reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            User _user = null;


            while (reader.Read())
            {
                _user = new User
               {
                   UserID = Guid.Parse(reader["UserID"].ToString()),
                   FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString(),
                   LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString(),
                   GroupName = reader["GroupName"].ToString(),
                   Email = reader["Email"].ToString(),
                   Cell = reader["Cell"].ToString()

                };
            }
            return _user;



        }
```

I need it to return the user object in JSON

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the contents of your web.config?

Comment: How did you publish your project? Does it work when you running from VS Code or VS 2017?

Comment: I ran a terminal command in VSCode. Yes I'll edit and add the web.config.

Comment: i think I ran dotnet publish -c release

Comment: it does work when i run it from vscode